# Allocating memory with malloc getting error

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
int *score;
score=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
int i;
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",sizeof(int)*i+score);
}
printf("ok");
```

In the above code I get an error but when I comment the last line `printf` the program runs correctly.
what is the problem??
(I want to give n number from user without using arrays)

Comment: `scanf("%d",sizeof(int)*i+score);`-->`scanf("%d",&score[i]);` and `score=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);`-->`score=malloc(sizeof(int)*n);`

Comment: then do this `scanf("%d",score+i);`

Comment: of `scanf("%d", &score[i]);`. And check return value of scanf.

Comment: @M.M.: That's what was being mentioned and then OP commented a requirement *I shouldn't use [ or ]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic of the form `score + i` is already done in multiples of `sizeof(*score)`. So when you write `score + i * sizeof(int)` you doubly multiply by the size of the items. You reach way beyond the bounds of the buffer.

Either write it simply as `score + i`, or if you insist on doing the multiplication yourself, be sure to cast to a character pointer type first:

```
(int*)((char*)score + i * sizeof(int))
```

Oh, and [don't cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). C doesn't require it, and it's somewhat unidiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d",sizeof(int)*i+score);
```

pointer arithmetic uses the pointer type, so here you are moving to sizeof(int)*i*sizeof(int) bytes after score, instead just use scores+i.